# program has stopped working

Tags: c++

I have a problem with a compiled program in C++. I have written a program and when I type something in the program I instantly receive this message:

http://abload.de/image.php?img=hweteu89.png

Here is the translation:

> program has stopped working
>
> A problem caused the program to work correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

Here is my source code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{float SLN,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R123,R23,R1234,R12345,R78,R678,R12345678,Rg,Uq=12+(SLN*0,1),Ig,I10,I9,I12345678,I12345,I678,U10,I6,U6,U78=I678*R78,I7,I8,U12345,U1234=U12345,U5=U12345,I1234,U123,U4,I5,U1=U123,I1,U2,U3,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,M,I2,I3=I2,I4=U4/R4,U7=U78,U8=U78,U9=I9*R9,Pg,Pg1;
cout<<"Bitte geben sie die Schülerlistennumer ein."<<endl;
cin>>SLN;//SLN eingeben



//Widerstandsvariablen definieren
R1=100;
R2=200;
R4=400;
R5=500;
R7=700;
R8=800;
R10=1000;

//Widerstände berechnen

R3=SLN*25;
R6=1000-(SLN*15);
R9=SLN*20;
R23=R2+R3;
R123=(R23*R1)/(R23+R1);
R1234=R123+R4;
R12345=(R1234*R5)/(R1234+R5);
R78=(R7*R8)/(R7+R8);
R678=R6+R78;
R12345678=R12345+R678;
Rg=1/((1/R12345678)+(1/R9)+(1/R10));

//Ströme berechnen
Ig=Uq/Rg;
I10=Uq/R10;
I9=Uq/R9;
I12345678=Uq/R12345678;
I12345=I12345678;
I678=I12345678;
I6=I678;
I7=U78/R7;
I8=U78/R8;
I1234=U1234/R1234;
I5=U5/R5;
I1=U1/R1;
I2=I12345678;


U10=I10*R10;
U6=I6*R6;
U12345=I12345*R12345;
U123=I1234*R123;
U4=I1234*R4;
U2=R2*I12345678;
U3=R3*I12345678;


//Leistungen berechnen
P1=I1*U1;
P2=I2*U2;
P3=I3*U3;
P4=I4*U4;
P5=I5*U5;
P6=I6*U6;
P7=I7*U7;
P8=I8*U8;
P9=I9*U9;
P10=I10*U10;
Pg=Uq*Ig;
Pg1=P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6+P7+P8+P9+P10;




//Variablen ausgeben(Spannung)
cout<<"Die spannung U1 betraegt"<<U1<<"Volt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die spannung U2 beträgt"<<U2<<"Volt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die spannung U3 betraegt"<<U3<<"Volt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die spannung U4 betraegt"<<U4<<"Volt."<<endl;     
cout<<"Die spannung U5 betraegt"<<U5<<"Volt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die spannung U6 betraegt"<<U6<<"Volt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die spannung U7 betraegt"<<U7<<"Volt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die spannung U8 betraegt"<<U8<<"Volt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die spannung U9 betraegt"<<U9<<"Volt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die spannung U10 betraegt"<<U10<<"Volt."<<endl;

//Variablen ausgeben (Strom)
cout<<"Der Strom I1 betraegt"<<I1<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I2 betraegt"<<I2<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I3 betraegt"<<I3<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I4 betraegt"<<I5<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I5 betraegt"<<I5<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I6 betraegt"<<I6<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I7 betraegt"<<I7<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I8 betraegt"<<I8<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I9 betraegt"<<I9<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom I10 betraegt"<<I10<<"Ampere."<<endl;
cout<<"Der Strom Iges betraegt"<<Ig<<"Ampere."<<endl;

//Variable ausgeben(Leistung)
cout<<"Die Leistung P1 betraegt "<<P1<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P2 betraegt "<<P2<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P3 betraegt "<<P3<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P4 betraegt "<<P4<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P5 betraegt "<<P5<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P6 betraegt "<<P6<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P7 betraegt "<<P7<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P8 betraegt "<<P8<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P9 betraegt "<<P9<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung P10 betraegt "<<P10<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung Pges betraegt "<<Pg<<"Watt."<<endl;
cout<<"Die Leistung Pg1 betraegt "<<Pg1<<"Watt."<<endl;


//Maschenregel ausgeben
M=U5-U10+U8+U6;
cout<<"Bei der Machenregel kommt"<<M<<"heraus."<<endl;




    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would really appreciate help how to fix this error.

Comment: you should learn to use loops -.-

Comment: and how does this help me to get rid of tghis error?

Comment: It would make it much easier to read the code. That in turn might make it easier to spot the error(s).

Comment: ya thats true but i didnt knew how to make it so yea

Comment: All of those assignments in that horrific first line are undefined behavior. You are taking the values of _uninitialized variables_ and using them in calculations or assignments.

Comment: Also as far as readability: you seem to have too much (multiple blank lines) or too little (lacking space between operators) whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

The comments are true.  You should learn to use loops.

Having said that, the issue is more than likely you are using uninitialized variables.  See this:

```
U78=I678*R78
```

The value of I678 is uninitialized, but you're using it to compute U78.  My Visual Studio also reports these variables as being used before initialization:

`1>warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'R78' used
1>warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'U12345' used
1>warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'U123' used
1>warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'I2' used
1>warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'U4' used
1>warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'R4' used
1>warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'I9' used
1>warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'R9' used`

You're using these directly or indirectly in the lines that do the division, so if they are uninitialized, the program will exhibit undefined behavior.  So initialize your variables, format your code better so that a line isn't an umpteen characters in length, and start to use loops.

Comment: I don't know what you're program is supposed to do.  That's your job.  What you can't do is use uninitialized variables.  Right now, those variables I listed will have any random value.  It could be 0, -10, 23432432.43243, -867867, who knows.  You don't know, I don't know, and nobody knows what the value of those variables are each time your program runs.  So go over your requirements for the program and give those variables a value that makes sense before you use them.